# Search database using a label to find an exact phrase

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I am using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2019. I have an access database that contains a memo field (Ingredients) that has multiple lines like:

> 0.75 oz    White Rum
>
> 0.75 oz    Vodka
>
> 3.0 oz     Pineapple Juice
>
> 1.0 oz     Sweet and sour mix
>
> 0.5 oz     Blue Curacao

A data-bound label (label49) displays the name of a specific ingredient. I am trying to fill a `DataGridView` (DataGridView1) with the names of cocktails that have that ingredient in it. The grid only has one column displayed "`CocktailName`"

I am using this code:

```
Me.NAIngredientsBindingSource.Sort = "Ingredient ASC"  'Data Table of Ingredients
Me.CocktailsBindingSource.Filter = Nothing   'Data Table of Cocktails
Me.CocktailsBindingSource.Filter = "Ingredients Like '*" & Label49.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "*'"
```

My problem is that using the wildcard `Like '*" & Label49.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "*'"` does not distinguish between Apple, Apple Juice, Pineapple, or Pineapple Juice.

These four items show the same cocktails in the DataGridView.

Is there a way to search for the exact ingredient as displayed in label49 that will recognize the differences?

Comment: Can I see an example of exactly what is displayed in Label49.Text.

Comment: How about giving your controls meaningful names. Label49 could IblIngrediantToSearch

Comment: Actually this may be a design flaw in your database. All the ingrediants, quantities and measure lumped together is a memo field is not ideal.

Comment: Agree with Mary, really sounds like you would be better to review the design a bit, but anyway, you are exactly right with you're problem.  That is the way Like works.  About the only thing I can think of would be using regular expressions, but I'm not sure you can do that via the filter property on your binding source.

Comment: Mary: I agree about meaningful names and will fix it soon. The same for the design flaw.

Comment: Hursey:  I'll see what I can work out.

Comment: You mean you've added 48 other labels to your application and never once thought to yourself "Gee, this naming scheme is a bit hard work having to remember what each of these 48 labels are/having to look them up.. If only they were named more sensibly like `cocktailNameLabel`" ?!